# Magento 2.1 :: Custom Option Drop Down :: Add Image Upload Field

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-options

How can we add image upload option specially for dropdown,
and show it on frontend,
which i did on magento 1.9[image]

Comment: Are You solved it